# flask wtforms dynamically show form fields based on select field

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a form to kick off generation of a few different types of files, and each type has different input parameters. I'd like to use a generic form, and based on the type selected, show only the relevant parameters.

The python code is

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField, DecimalField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import Optional, InputRequired
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, render_template, url_for

bp = Blueprint("routes", __name__)


class genericForm(FlaskForm):
    # populate the file types, with default option empty
    fileType = SelectField("File type",
                           choices=[(None, ""),
                                    ("file1", "file1"),
                                    ("file2", "file2"),
                                    ("file3", "file3")],
                           validators=[DataRequired()])
    required1 = IntegerField("Required 1", validators=[InputRequired()])
    required2 = IntegerField("Required 2", validators=[InputRequired()])

    optional1 = DecimalField("Optional 1", validators=[Optional()])
    optional2 = DecimalField("Optional 2", validators=[Optional()])
    optional3 = DecimalField("Optional 3", validators=[Optional()])
    optional4 = DecimalField("Optional 4", validators=[Optional()])


@bp.route("/index", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    """The index"""
    form = genericForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        identifier = createFile(form)
        return redirect(url_for("routes.files", info=identifier))
    # which file types require which form fields
    fileFields = {"file1": "optional1", "optional3",
                  "file2": "optional2", "optional3",
                  "file4": "optional1", "optional4"}
    return render_template("index.html", form=form, fileFields=fileFields)
```

and the jinja template I currently have is

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
    <h1>{% block title %}File Creation{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.flags.required %}
                {{ field.label }} {{ field }}<br />
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </p>

        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

But what I'm trying to do is determine whether to hide a field based on whether it's required or if it's in the list for the selected `fileType`, and update that when the selected `fileType` changes